# Why is my Binomial Theorem not working?

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-theorem

Ok this might seem like a dumb question which I think it is but it is really bugging me.

Lets say you have a 1 in 5 chance at something ( doesn't matter what) and you get 2 attempts at it. By basic probability you can just take the inverse and multiply by 2 subtracting the result by 1.
      $$1-(.80*.80) = .36$$
Or 36% which seems simple enough but now do the same problem incorporating the `Binomial theorem`

$${n \choose k}*p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$$
or

$${2 \choose 1}*(.20)^1*(1-.20)^{2-1} = .32$$

$.32 \neq .36$ last time I checked. So will someone please tell me what foolish thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first number you computed, $0.36$, is the probability of *at least* one success, which is the opposite of all failures.

The second number, $0.32$, is the probability of *exactly* one success, which leaves out the case of two successes. If you add the probability of exactly 2 successes (namely, $(1/5)^2=0.04$) to this number, you obtain your first answer.

Comment: haha! What a fool I am. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks man